# Blank terminal after  removing "fortune cow"

Tags: command-line

After removing the "fortune cow" for terminal, I'm getting a blank terminal and can't actually do anything in it (I can write but I can't install, remove or update anything).

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please post more information, maybe a screenshot?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=34p1h7t&s=6   it just says : PRogram "fortune" isnt installed.You can install it by entering : sudo apt-get install fortune-mod    ,thats it

Answer (score 2):

How did you remove fortune cow?

To try and fix your problem:

Open up a console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>  and type:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Check for references to `cowsay` or `fortune` and remove or comment those lines.

Another file you can look in is `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback,but its not responding,yes i have removed fortune,but i added some extra lines to get it up on startup of the terminal

Comment: What is not responding? And how did you removed fortune? You must erase any invocations to fortune on bash related files, like .bashrc or .bash_profile

Comment: I have removed the fortune cow by adding a line into terminal : sudp apt-remove cowsay .But when I isntalled the fortune cow,I added soem automatic line,so it start when I open the terminal.I looked into bash.scr but there is no reference to cowsay.Do you need a screenshot.The terminal is not responding,i can open it ,but i cant do anything in it..i can write but nothing happens . the ss : http://oi47.tinypic.com/nd4qro.jpg

Comment: You have to remove that automatic line you added.

Comment: but how do i remove it,i just copy-pasted it into terminal.In bash.scr there is no reference to the added lines that i have added. :(

Comment: What about  /etc/bash.bashrc ? Do you have any line there about fortune?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
I figured it out (sort of).
Opened terminal, went to Edit tab, Profile Preferences on drop down menu, Color, un-check 'use colors from system theme',  changed font colour to Yellow and background colour to black
One other thing, I know I didn't change anything but terminal title has changed from 'Terminal' to pj@ubuntu:~$